# Force redirect single.php to index

Tags: ajax, redirect, htaccess, single

I want to make a force redirect for single.php to index so that it is never reachable by direct access (the site is built in a way that you retrieve all the content on the index page, still need to have this page available though because of an ajax function). I assume this is done in .htaccess?

Edit: I need to be able to access the single.php through an ajax request from the index page, i.e. the redirect should only occur upon direct url access.

Comment: You can delete single.php file and index.php will be used instead, or that isn't options in your case?

Comment: No, I still need the single page. Otherwise I would have solved it long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this code in functions.php file

```
add_action('wp', 'myfun');
 function myfun(){ 
    if(is_single()){ 
            wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;  
        }

  }
```

hope this trick solve your problem. all the best ;)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :) Plus points for not having to dig into WP's dreaded .htaccess...

Comment: Ok, so maybe I got a little bit too excited. If I try and fetch the single page now via an ajax load from the index page, I simply return index itself. It seems it redirects to index either way you choose to access it. How can this be avoided?

Comment: try this...
pass a parameter with ajax request url. here I am using "mode" parameter for example...
add_action('wp', 'myfun');
 function myfun(){ 
 $mode = $_REQUEST['mode'];
 if(is_single() && !$mode == 'ajax'){ wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;  }
 
  }

Comment: That did it! Just realised I need to maintain the URL from the direct access though but I think I can solve that on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try,

```
add_action('wp', 'myfun');
function myfun(){ 

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=='XMLHttpRequest' && is_single()){

       //ajax function here

    } elseif (if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=='' && is_single())) {

            wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;  

    }

}
```

Or here is a JavaScript based solution from [Ben Heller](http://www.spruce.it/noise/prevent-direct-access-to-wordpress-single-post-pages-using-javascript-ajax-trick) on this very topic,

```
if (window.top.location == window.location) {
   window.location.replace("<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl');?>#work");
}
```

Or as suggested by [techguy4web](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/20389/techguy4web) you can pass a custom parameter and check for its existence much in the same fashion.

### Some supporting material:

- [things-to-know-about-ajax/header-switching.html](http://icant.co.uk/articles/things-to-know-about-ajax/header-switching.html)
- [ajax-requested-page-return-only-content/](http://digwp.com/2011/02/ajax-requested-page-return-only-content/)
- [prevent-direct-access-to-wordpress-single-post-pages-using-javascript-ajax-trick](http://www.spruce.it/noise/prevent-direct-access-to-wordpress-single-post-pages-using-javascript-ajax-trick)

### WordPress plugins:

**Ajax Content Renderer**

> Sometimes you just need to retrieve the body of a post or page without
>   the header, footer and their includes. This plugin detects Ajax
>   requests and returns just the formatted body of the post or page.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-content-renderer/

**Infinite Scroll**

> Automatically append the next page of posts (via AJAX) to your page
>   when a user scrolls to the bottom.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/infinite-scroll/

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go along with techguy4web's solution.

Comment: No problem, probably a more reliable option since headers can be **spoofed**, though I've provided some additional information anyway as to other alternative solutions should anyone else find your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tamplate_include` filter and force WordPress to retrieve index.php instead of single.php.

```
function mamaduka_template_include( $template ) {
    if ( is_single() )
        $template = get_index_template();

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'mamaduka_template_include' );
```